# UILabel in different position for 2 different screen sizes

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel that i placed in the top left corner of the screen in the Storyboards. I disabled "Autolayout" and it works perfectly fine on the iPhone 5 screen. The problem comes when i try them on any of the smaller screens like the iPhone 4. The label is then placed on the bottom right corner. After this issue, i tried to programmatically 'fix' the position in the "viewDidLoad" method of the view controller, but it stills moves position and the problem continues.

Ive been scratching my head about this for a while!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posting some code would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you turn autolayout back on. If you get the constraints right, this situation (two different screen sizes) is *exactly* the sort of thing autolayout is really good for. There's a very good reason why Apple migrated autolayout from OS X to iOS at exactly the moment the iPhone 5 screen appeared on the scene!

Comment: Ive tried using Auto-layout but to me it seems more of a hassle than a help. I cant seem to overwrite the constraints put in automatically which completely screw up the views

Comment: Well, it's an art. :) You have to make outlets to the constraints you want to change, if needed. Or you have to learn to manipulate the way the nib/storyboard makes constraints. This section of my book http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout and this one http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_constraints_in_the_nib might help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to fix it at [viewWillAppear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the utilities panel, click the tab "Show size inspector", and change the autosizing. Then drag your component in your storyboard's view so that it stays in one of the "borders". If you do not need to support older iOS versions, I'd recommend you to figure the proper way with auto-layout though.